# Auto Renewal Opportunities and copy previous opportunity product to Newly created opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement where I want auto opportunity to be created when stage is closed won on opportunity. I was able to achieve this with some of the fields populated. Now I also want products from old opportunity to be copied to the newly created opportunity.

```
trigger NewOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<opportunity> lstopp = new List<opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){

        if(opp.stageName == 'closed won'){

            opportunity newopp = new opportunity(AccountID = opp.AccountID, StageName = 'Prospecting', Name = opp.Name, CloseDate = opp.CloseDate, Amount = opp.Amount);
            lstopp.add(newopp);
        }

        if(lstopp.size()>0){
            insert lstopp;

        }




    }

}
```

Comment: Whats the issue? What you already tried?

Comment: I want to create new opportunity automatically when stage name is closed won ...... I am able to create new opportunity depending upon that ........ Now i have junction object opportunity product .I want all the fields of opportunity product on old opportunity need to be copied to the newly created opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use describe to get all field and Populate them in Set, Filter using `iscreateable` to to avoid all formula and other fields.

```
String obj = 'Opportunity';
Set<string> OpportunityFieldSet = new Set<string>()
Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(obj); 
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sobjType.getDescribe(); 
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = describeResult.fields.getMap(); 
for(Schema.SObjectField sch : fieldsMap.values())
{
  if(sch.getDescribe().iscreateable())
    OpportunityFieldSet.add( sch);
}
```

Now use this set in you code

```
for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){

        if(opp.stageName == 'closed won'){
            opportunity newopp = new opportunity();
           for(string str : OpportunityFieldSet)
               newopp.put(str= opp.get(str));
           lstopp.add(newopp);
        }

        if(lstopp.size()>0){
            insert lstopp;

        }
```

using this approach you can easily get all fields dynamically.

Comment: I want opportunity product fields   need to be copied to the auto created new opportunity from old opportunity .......... Here we are looping on opportunity  ....... Do we get all those fields in opportunity product object?

Comment: @anjali if you want to change this for line item then you can follow same steps for line items as well. Get all dynamic fields and make a query and then using same approach populate them.